# Why was Jörg Haider so disliked by European leaders?

Tags: european-union, public-opinion, austria

According to [this](http://www.nytimes.com/2000/02/05/news/05iht-react.2.t_0.html) NY Times article from 2000, many European nations and even America put various sanctions on Austria to prevent Jörg Haider from gaining power there. The only reason the NY Times gave is that he is "far right" which doesn't tell me anything other than the NY Times doesn't like him either. What were some specific things Mr. Haider has done or said that have caused so much desire to keep him from power?

Comment: @Philipp Thanks for the edit. I was trying to find the reason for this question: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11023/why-can-the-eu-stop-member-countries-from-electing-democratically-representative/11024#11024 and ran across the NY Times article without realizing it was 16 years old. I don't follow European politics much.

Comment: Does [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B6rg_Haider) help?

Answer (score 5):

Far right is often used as a polite way of saying that someone is racist or guilty of other isms, without explicitly saying so, because virtually everyone says they're not racist nowadays.

Going on recollections he was perceived as being a neonazi in policy regardless of whether he self-identifies that way, and many people regard that as bad.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question. Also "far right" is used different ways. For example here's the Chicago Tribune referring to Ted Cruz, a candidate with no hints of racism, being called "far-right". http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/nationworld/politics/ct-why-ted-cruz-should-worry-2016-republicans-too-20160406-story.html  American newspapers don't have a consistent definition of words like 'far right', 'conservative', 'right-wing', etc. Those words can be applied equally to free speech advocates and free speech opponents, to racists and to proponents of equality under the law.etc

Comment: @Readin The left/right dichtomy has a different meaning in Europe than it has in the United States. In Europe "right" usually means nationalist, authoritarian and/or racist. But I also agree that the left/right dichtomy is a dangerous oversimplification of political orientations.

Comment: Are you implying that there are closet-racists these days? I had never even considered that could exist!

Answer (score 5):

From Wikipedia's [summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B6rg_Haider#Political_views), Heider attacked Islam declaring it incompatible with democracy. He also contested bilingualism in the southern region of Austria where his fief was. The target of the latter contestation was the Slovene minority there.

And these bits may be from a [source](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40209430) somewhat more biased (against Heider) , but since I can't find much else in English on his deeper political philosophy... based on a book he wrote in the 1990s, his ideal of democracy appears to have been a presidential republic with no political parties (although he would allow for "movements") and in which the people are consulted through referendums (it's not too clear how regular he envisaged those to be.) He railed against "the party state", which was more or less his version of the "deep state", but with emphasis on problems he saw with the elite-parties link. Likewise, the same source says that it was pretty hard to get Heider to condemn anything the Nazis did, with interviewers at best managing to get statements from him like "If you want, then you can call Auschwitz mass murder."

Some of the other themes of his, including a focus on ["Austria first"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96sterreich_zuerst)--this was literally the name of his referendum campaign to change Austria's asylum and immigration polices, as well as rhetorical focus on "crimes committed by foreigners" (Ausländerkriminalität) have become more mainstream with the right-wing in the meantime (world-wide), but in the 1990s and early 2000s, they were not that common/mainstream in Europe. (The turnout at the Heider-initiated referendum was only 7%.)